# Why my .app file (which will use for testing the app in simulator) in mac is coming with disable icon?

Tags: iphone, xcode, ionic-framework, ios-simulator, browserstack

I am working with Ionic Framework. My objective is to run my application in Simulator through XCode. After constantly tried to run my App through Xcode's simulator, I observed two issues :

1 . Simulator is opening with following Error messages: **The Operation could not be completed. No such process. Domain: NSPOSIXErrorDomain, Code = 3,  Failure Reason: No such process**
[image]

2. My .app file under my project is coming with **disabled** icon

I tried by Cleaning Build Project & even with `xcrun simctl install device_id app_Path` as well but no luck. It will really help if anybody can share their thought on this issue.

Comment: The "disabled" icon is normal. This is not an app that can run on your computer; it is iOS-only.

Comment: Thank you for your prompt reply. Any suggestion/clue about first error as well  (The Operation could not be completed. No such process. Domain: NSPOSIXErrorDomain, Code = 3, Failure Reason: No such process)

Answer (score 0):

I keep trying switching between Simulator device with older iOS versions. Somehow my app got started running in Simulator. Also, do Product > Clean Build Folder.